# Occasionally unable to edit posts in low quality review queue

Tags: bug, review

Sometimes, when I try to edit a question that I encounter in the *Low Quality Posts* review queue, I am unable to. Specifically, the standard edit page opens, but I am unable to actually edit the text in the box, though I can still select it. As far as I can tell, this *only* happens when I click the edit button in the low quality posts queue, and even then only happens about 10% of the time.

Comment: How can we replicate this behaviour?

Comment: @Werner: It appears to happen randomly, but relatively frequently. I would suspect you could replicate it if you have someone with an account similar to mine (roughly the same rep, not a moderator) try to edit a bunch of low quality posts. I would guess that 20 would be enough to see it at least once, unless this is something that only affects me.

Comment: The next time this happens, could you post a link to the specific review entry? You can find the link after you've completed the review via the [review queue history](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) or [your own review activity log](http://stackoverflow.com/users/789750/dan?tab=activity&sort=reviews). This _might_ at least give someone some idea of what's going on here.

Comment: Also, have you checked if this happens on all browsers, or just a specific one?